# New iPhone 8 restore not showing sms messages

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, sms

My new iPhone 8 is not showing sms messages after a restore using itunes.

Created a backup of old iPhone 3G (ios 4.1) and restored it to new iPhone 8 (ios 11). Notes, contacts and calendar have all transferred over fine but not my sms messages. Every time I open the messages app its blank.

If I open the sqlite db on the backup it shows all the messages, the file size is 3mb. But if I look under general-> iPhone storage-> messages its 12kb

If I use ibackup viewer I can also see all the messages in the backup fine.

Is there anything I can do to view my old sms messages on the new phone or transfer the messages to it?

Edit:

What I've tried:
Backup old phone, restore it to new one, no sms messages display on new phone.
Opened sqlite db, can see all the sms messages fine.
Looked at all the posts on here, googled for 6 hours tying things but nothing will transfer them over, or I just cant see them.
Reset all the settings.

What I cant get is the sms messages to display in the new iPhone

Comment: There's many answers on this site regarding restoring/exporting sms messages.  Have you searched for those answers and tried the solutions?  If so, please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, whether it worked/didn't work/partially worked, etc.  This will help avoid answers for solutions you've already attempted.

Comment: Can export fine, can't restore, it just doesn't show my old sms messages from the backup restore.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same situation that some of my photos and messages were not restored successfully. But now, all my files on old iPhone 5S have been moved to my new iPhone 8. It just takes me 5 minutes to transfer about 2000 photos. Maybe you can also get solution here: [transfer all files to new iPhone](http://www.imobie.com/support/transfer-data-to-new-iphone.htm)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but none of these tools modify the sqlite db, I had to buy another older iphone with an older ios used to convert the db to the new format then restore that backup to the new iphone.